# I want to know about the prospects of working in Singapore

Tags: working, singapore, work-permit

I worked for a brief period in Singapore at a work pass, provided to me by the employer. However, as it turned out, they communicated a different work profile at time of recruitment and when I joined, the work was not the same. Therefore, I had to leave that job.

My query is that in any way, can that company impact my work prospects in Singapore? If yes, what could be the remedies.

Comment: IMO, more a legal issue than a traveling issue; anyway, you'd probably need a proper work visa if you want to work in Singapore again.

Comment: Did you fulfil the terms of your contract before leaving eg work a notice period?

Answer (score 1):

**Leaving your job is an issue with your employer, not the Singaporean government.** As long as your tax obligations were settled, you should have no issue getting a new work pass.

That said, Singapore has tightened up its work visa issuance policies considerably since COVID hit, so it may not be as easy to get the work pass as it was last time.